AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_items_color'
I'm trying to create a simple Drawer with three clickable items, the first of which should route my to an other Screen.
I've got not idea why this error shows up:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_items_color'

and I've found no help in kivy or kivymd docs.
I have kivy version 2.3.0, kivmd version 2.0.1.dev0 and python version 3.12.3. Can someone help me with this? I've just updated kivymd to the new version and im trying to learn kivy and kivymd in the process but its not being easy.
This is my .py file:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random as rd

Window.size = (360,640)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_file("myKv.kv")
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette ="Orange"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        return screen
    
class EntryWindow(MDScreen):
    #on_enter functions fire prior to the screen being set,
    #therefore this is the proper way to do it
    def on_enter(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.go_home, 3)
        print(self.manager.screens)  # note screens is not yet set here...

    def go_home(self, _):
        print(self.manager.screens)  # screens is set at this time
        self.manager.current = "home"     

class Home(MDScreen):
    pass


class Gender(MDScreen):
    
    def on_enter(self):
        self.ids.extractedWord.color = (1,1,1,1)
        f = open(".venv/genderWordDatabase.txt")
        red = f.readlines()
        stripped = [elem.strip() for elem in red]
        separato = [elem.split() for elem in stripped]
        dizWords = {}
        for i in separato:
            dizWords[i[1]] = (i[0],i[2])
        print(dizWords)
        extracted = list(dizWords.keys())[rd.randint(0,len(dizWords)-1)]
        self.ids.extractedWord.font_style = "H6"
        self.ids.extractedWord.text = extracted
    
    def recordUpdate(self,extractedWord,operand):
        f = open(".venv/genderWordDatabase.txt", "r")
        red = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        for i in range(0,len(red)):
            if extractedWord in red[i]:
                red[i] = " ".join(red[i].strip("\n").split()[:-1]) + " " + str(int(red[i].strip("\n").split()[2])+operand)+"\n"
        g = open(".venv/genderWordDatabase.txt", "w")
        g.writelines(red)
        
    def wordExtraction(self):
        self.ids.extractedWord.color = (1,1,1,1)
        f = open(".venv/genderWordDatabase.txt")
        red = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        stripped = [elem.strip() for elem in red]
        separato = [elem.split() for elem in stripped]
        dizWords = {}
        for i in separato:
            dizWords[i[1]] = (i[0],i[2])
        extracted = list(dizWords.keys())[rd.randint(0,len(dizWords)-1)]
        self.ids.extractedWord.font_style = "Display"
        self.ids.extractedWord.text = extracted
    
    def check(self, answer):
        f = open(".venv/genderWordDatabase.txt")
        red = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        stripped = [elem.strip("\n").strip() for elem in red]
        separato = [elem.split() for elem in stripped]
        dizWords = {}
        for i in separato:
            dizWords[i[1]] = (i[0],i[2])
        print(dizWords)
        parola  = self.ids.extractedWord.text
        if dizWords[parola][0] == answer:
            self.ids.extractedWord.color = (0,1,0,1)
            self.ids.extractedWord.font_style = "Display"
            self.ids.extractedWord.text = "Right +1"
            #Chiamo la funzione che aggiorna il record di ciascuna parola
            self.recordUpdate(dizWords[parola][0],1)
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.wordExtraction(), 1)
        else:
            self.ids.extractedWord.color = (1,0,0,1)
            self.ids.extractedWord.font_style = "Display"
            self.ids.extractedWord.text = "Wrong -1, the correct one was: " + dizWords[self.ids.extractedWord.text][0]
            self.recordUpdate(dizWords[parola][0],-1)
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.wordExtraction(), 2)

MainApp().run()

and this is my .kv file:
ScreenManager:
    EntryWindow:
    Home:
    Gender:
    
<EntryWindow>:
    name: "starting"
    BoxLayout: 
        orientation: "vertical"
        Widget:
        MDLabel:
            text: "German"
            halign: "center"
            markup: True
            color: (1,1,1,1)
            font_style: "Display"
        MDLabel:
            text: "By Staffo"
            markup: True
            color: (1,1,1,1)
            halign: "center"
            font_style: "Display"
        Widget:
        Widget:

<Home>:
    name: "home"
    MDNavigationLayout:
        MDScreenManager:
            MDScreen:
                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: "center"
                    anchor_y: "center"
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        padding: 10
                        spacing: 20
                        MDButton:
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.1, "center_y":0.9}
                            on_release: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
                            MDIconButton:
                                icon: "menu"
                                style: "standard"
                        Widget:
                        MDCard:
                            padding: 10
                            MDRelativeLayout:
                                MDLabel:
                                    text:"Trial"
                        MDCard:
                            padding: 10
                            MDRelativeLayout:
                                MDLabel:
                                    text:"Trial"
                        MDCard:
                            padding: 10
                            MDRelativeLayout:
                                MDLabel:
                                    text:"Trial"
                        Widget:
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            radius: 0, dp(16), dp(16), 0
            MDNavigationDrawerMenu:
                MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
                    orientation:"vertical"
                    padding: (0, 0, 0, "12dp")
                    adaptive_height: True
                    MDLabel: 
                        text: "Menu"
                        adaptive_height: True
                        #padding_x: "16dp"
                        font_style: "Display"
                        role: "small"
                    
                    MDNavigationDrawerDivider:
                    MDNavigationDrawerItem:
                        active_indicator_color: "#e7e4c0"
                        #on_release: root.manager.current = "gender"
                        MDNavigationDrawerItemLeadingIcon:
                            icon: "book-open-variant"
                            theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                            icon_color: "#4a4939"
                        MDNavigationDrawerItemText:
                            text: "Words' Gender"
                    MDNavigationDrawerItem:
                        active_indicator_color: "#e7e4c0"
                        MDNavigationDrawerItemLeadingIcon:
                            icon: "pencil-plus"
                            theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                            icon_color: "#4a4939"
                        MDNavigationDrawerItemText:
                            text: "Personalize Dictionary"
                    MDNavigationDrawerItem:
                        active_indicator_color: "#e7e4c0"
                        MDNavigationDrawerItemLeadingIcon:
                            icon: "cog"
                            theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                            icon_color: "#4a4939"
                        MDNavigationDrawerItemText:
                            text: "Settings"                                               
<Gender>:
    name: "gender"
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "center"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Widget:
            MDButton:
                style: "outlined"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                on_press: root.manager.current = "home"
                MDButtonText:
                    text: "Home"
                
                
            Widget:
            MDCard:
                size_hint: .85, 2 
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                MDRelativeLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        halign: "center"
                        id: extractedWord
                        markup: True
                        text: "extractedWord"
                        font_style: "Display"
                        color: (0,0,0,1)
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 20
                Widget:
                MDButton:  
                    on_press: root.check("der")
                    MDButtonText:
                        text: "[b]der[/b]"
                        markup: True
                        text_color: (1,1,1,1)
                MDButton:  
                    on_press: root.check("die")
                    MDButtonText:
                        text: "[b]die[/b]"
                        markup: True
                        text_color: (1,1,1,1)
                MDButton:  
                    on_press: root.check("das")
                    MDButtonText:
                        text: "[b]das[/b]"
                        markup: True
                        text_color: (1,1,1,1) 
                Widget:
            Widget:
            Widget:
            Widget:
            Widget:


Please reduce your code to a [mre], and post the full traceback of the error. There's no use of update_items_color in the code you show, so it's impossible to tell where it's happening and what might be the cause.

please use context managers for opening files. it makes your code easier to read (what you do with the file is kept in its own block) and you can't forget to close a file like you probably did in Gender.on_enter

@UlrichEckhardt i don't think it's an obvious error. see MDNavigationDrawerItem AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_active_color'

Barnard is correct that full error trace back is needed.
The attribute [method - .update_items_color(item: MDNavigationDrawerItem)]
is found in the following class:
kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer.navigationdrawer.MDNavigationDrawerMenu

https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/navigationdrawer/
The corresponding section is found in your .kv file.
MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        radius: 0, dp(16), dp(16), 0
        MDNavigationDrawerMenu:
            MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
                orientation:"vertical"...

So what is getting the incorrect/ None type object that should get a MDNavigationDrawerMenu Object and calling that method.

I don't understand your last phrase. I saw this in the docs: "update_items_color(item: MDNavigationDrawerItem) → None" but frankly I don't know what to make of it. It doesn't specify how to use that method and neither when it fires.
